# Capture Groups with Multiple Delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, capture-group

In Javascript, I have ascii text lines, and each line can have multiple groups of $ delimited text, as shown below.

---

Input Text: `In the quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, $a$ should not be $0$`

---

I need a performant way of creating an array, which should have either words or the delimited string. For example, after parsing the above line, I need to end up with

---

Desired Result: `["In", "the", "quadratic", "polynomial", "$ax^2 + bx + c$", "," "$a$", "should", "not", "be", "$0$]`

---

Pattern that is not helping: `"\\$(.|\v)*?\\$"`

---

Basically, I need to parse the string and pull out words which are space or tab separated, but I have to treat $ delimited text as a single word.

But that is really the end of my wits. Please help :-)

Comment: Can there be spaces or tabs in a `$` delimited section? For instance, `$ax^2 + bx + c$`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was sloppy when I forgot to include spaces. Sorry!

Comment: There can be spaces in the $ delimited text. And in the output, the entire $ delimited part needs to be retained as is, without any change. This part also I had missed in my first version of the question, but I just edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might use

```
\$[^$]*\$|\S+
```

- `\$` Match a $
- `[^$]*` Match 0+ times any char except $ (or use `[^$\r\n]*` to not cross newlines)
- `\$` Match a $
- `|` Or
- `\S+` Match 1+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHWDRI/1)

```js
const regex = /\$[^$]*\$|\S+/g;
const s = "In the quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, $a$ should not be $0$";
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right, I forgot to include spaces in my sample input. I edited the question and included spaces.

Comment: @srini.rgs - The updated answer handles spaces and tabs within delimited regions the way I think you want.

Comment: Yes. The Updated answer  fulfills my requirement. Absolutely. Thanks to you and @Thefourthbird